# FreeBSD run-time load address of shared object

Tags: linker, freebsd, elf

In linux, in the file dl-machine.h there's this function below to get the run-time load address of a shared object. Will this work in FreeBSD as well or is there a different way to do it?

```
/* Return the run-time load address of the shared object.  */
static inline ElfW(Addr) __attribute__ ((unused))
elf_machine_load_address (void)
{
  ElfW(Addr) addr;

  /* The easy way is just the same as on x86:
   leaq _dl_start, %0
   leaq _dl_start(%%rip), %1
   subq %0, %1
 but this does not work with binutils since we then have
 a R_X86_64_32S relocation in a shared lib.

 Instead we store the address of _dl_start in the data section
 and compare it with the current value that we can get via
 an RIP relative addressing mode.  Note that this is the address
 of _dl_start before any relocation performed at runtime.  In case
 the binary is prelinked the resulting "address" is actually a
 load offset which is zero if the binary was loaded at the address
 it is prelinked for.  */

  asm ("lea _dl_start(%%rip), %0\n\t"
   "sub 1f(%%rip), %0\n\t"
   ".section\t.data.rel.ro\n"
   "1:\t" ASM_ADDR " _dl_start\n\t"
   ".previous\n\t"
   : "=r" (addr) : : "cc");

  return addr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file `dl-machine.h` doesn't exist on FreeBSD (at least not on 10.1 amd64).

On FreeBSD just like on Linux you can get the address of symbols in a shared object with [`dlsym`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dlopen&sektion=3).

The main difference is that FreeBSD also provides `dlfunc` to get the addresses of functions without a compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dladdr()` to get the base address of a shared object given an address elsewhere in the object. If you're calling the function from within code in the shared object that is pretty straightforward.